# Unable to get value of a JS variable using Cheerio

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

I have a [web page](http://www.watchfree.to/watch-366-Forrest-Gump-movie-online-free-putlocker.html) in which I have multiple scripts loaded. From this page how can I get the value of a JavaScript variable using Cheerio?

[image: js variable]

From above picture, i need the value of location.
I am using this code but it returns the only the first complete script:

```js
function getSecondBody()
{
    url2 = 'http://www.watchfree.to/watch-366-Forrest-Gump-movie-online-free-putlocker.html';
    request(url2, function(err, resp, body)
{
 var $  = cheerio.load(body);
    
 var embedcode = $('script');
  embedcodetext2 = embedcode;
 console.log(embedcodetext2);
 return embedcodetext2;
});
}
```

Comment: You get whole javascript code as a string? If you get it as a string you can apply regex on it to fetch the value. Regex would be something similar to this expression `var locations = \["(.*)"]`